# Meteor autoform with nested schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Can someone please tell me how I get Autoform to work with this nested schema?

```
date: {
        type: Number,
        max: new Date().getFullYear(),
        optional: true
    },
"date.estimated": {
        type: Boolean
    },
```

I have tried

```
            {{> afQuickField 'date.estimated'}}
```

With no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid.

```
"date.year": {
        type: Number,
        max: new Date().getFullYear(),
        optional: true
    },
"date.estimated": {
        type: Boolean
    },
```